# Getting error while creating dbo schema programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to create database,schema and tables through c# code and so far i have successfully created database but getting error
while creating schema:

I am trying to create below schema:

```
1) Person
2) Production
3) Sales
4) dbo
```

Now some tables have schema as Person and some tables have schema as dbo and so while creating tables i would like that tables to have appropriate schema.

[image]

I am not getting error while creating **Person,Production and sales** schema **but i get error while creating schema for dbo**.

> Error:The specified schema name "dbo" either does not exist or you do
>   not have permission to use it.CREATE SCHEMA failed due to previous
>   errors.

Code:
This is my code:

```
 conn.Open();
 foreach (var item in schemaList)
                    {
                        sqlQuery = "CREATE SCHEMA " + schema;
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                    {
                         cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    }
  conn.Close();
```

Why does this permission problems doesnt comes in case of creating other schema and why it comes only while creating dbo schema.

Comment: The `dbo` schema (and several others) always exists in any database. As such, it can't be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbo schema is created by default in your database and you cannot recreate it. Get a list of all schemas using:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.schemas
```

Or

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

Also if I may, your table names are more like columns to me. You might wanna reconsider how you use schemas, tables and the way you wanna communicate with your SQL server using c# code

Answer (score 1):

There are certain default Built-In Schemas are created by sql servere. **user can not drop them or create those schema.** below schema are Built-in.

1. dbo
2. guest
3. sys